# Extracting Google Analytics report for all pages

Tags: r, google-analytics, pageviews, google-query-language

I'm trying to import data from Google analytic s to R by using **rga** library and following line.

```
myresults <-  ga$getData(id, start.date="2015-04-28",
     end.date="2015-05-28", metrics = "ga:exits",start = 1,max = 1000)
```

Above code works and does extract information specified by query `"ga:exits",` and I was wondering if there exits a query that would provide a report of page views for every pages.

P.S. I have tried google analytics query explorer.

Sincerely, 
YJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3Axxxxxxxx&start-date=2015-05-01&end-date=2015-06-08&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a dimensions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets. For example, `ga:pageTitle` or `ga:pagePath`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ga:pagePath in the dimension and ga:pageviews in the metric.

```
    rga.open(instance = "ga", 
             client.id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxgooleusercontent.com", 
             client.secret = "xxxxx-xxxxe46z_N")

    ga$getData(ids,metrics="ga:pageviews", dimensions="ga:pagePath,
               start.date="yyyy-mm-dd",
               end.date="yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Hope this helps.